# open a new window inside the current window with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a prompt which will lead me to another site but I want the other site to replace the current window I was in.

The code:

```
<button id="butt">press</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('butt').onclick = function()
{
var age = parseInt(prompt("please enter your age", "18")); //parseInt turns the string to numbers
   if(age >= 18)
   {
       window.open('http://www.walla.co.il','walla');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set new location.href.

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.walla.co.il'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace method:

```
document.getElementById('butt').onclick = function()
{
var age = parseInt(prompt("please enter your age", "18")); //parseInt turns the string to numbers
   if(age >= 18)
   {
       window.location.replace('http://www.walla.co.il','walla');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("http://www.walla.co.il","_self");
```

Above line opens the url in the same page.

Comment: i tried that and it opens the window in the prompt. anyway people already told me the answer above but ty